# duplicate sub-module in different packages causing problems with py.test

Tags: python, module, pytest

We have a large system in Python.
top-level has two modules, top1 and top2.
top1 has the submodule sub1
top2 has the submodule sub2 which, it turns out, also has the submodule sub1.
So sub1 appears in two locations:

```
top/top1/sub1
top/top2/sub2/sub1
```

This is fine, except py.test is complaining the the second import of sub1 is causing a name conflict, because it's already seen the same symbols when it imported sub1.

Any clue on how to resolve this?

Comment: `import foo as bar`?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I realized.

Create a new file, `pytest.ini`, at the top level with these contents:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs = top/top2/sub2/sub1
```